# Twitter Bootstrap button click to toggle expand/collapse text section above button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have recently come accross bootstrap and I am working on extending the hero example. I want to add the following behaviour to my page:

When a button (i.e. an element with selector '.row .btn') is clicked on, I want to be able to toggle between expanding/collapsing the portion of text above the button.

This is what the HTML looks like:

```
<html>
  <head>
      <title>Test Page</title>
    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
      }
    </style>
    <link href="../assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="hero-unit">
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <p>Blah, blah.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
      </div>

      <!-- Example row of columns -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
           <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="../assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I can hack this using jQuery, but maybe there is a way of doing it the Bootstrap way? - i.e. using the Bootstrap API?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Based on [the doc](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse)

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4 collapse-group">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p class="collapse">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
        <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$('.row .btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var $collapse = $this.closest('.collapse-group').find('.collapse');
    $collapse.collapse('toggle');
});
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/68RXP/).

Comment: Short and sweet, it's even possible to add multiple collapsible items in a single group, great answer.

Comment: For IE11 it only expands, but does not collapse as well.

Comment: The demo fails to do anything for me.  I'm in Chrome Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit) on a Mac.

Answer (score 152):

It's possible to do this without using extra JS code using the data-collapse and data-target attributes on the a link.

e.g.

```
<a class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#viewdetails">View details &raquo;</a>
```

[Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Dc6jF/).

Comment: How would I toggle the button text to say, e.g., "Hide details", then switch back to "View details" when clicked?

Comment: This answer should be the default set up, but it becomes tedious to set `id="guid"` and `data-target="#guid"` if you have several elements that could be resolved via _relative_ selectors.

Comment: this was not the question, it is just a normal collapse.. I think the OP want to extend the text that is already present (sort of excerpt to full text expansion) EDIT: I am sorry that is what I wanted.. not the OP :(

Comment: For others, who like @DeanRichardson, want to toggle the button text between e.g. "View details..." and "Hide details..." see http://stackoverflow.com/a/28500651/245602

Comment: Actually, for IE11 it only expands, but does not collapse.

Answer (score 30):

Elaborating a bit more on Taylor Gautier's reply (sorry, I dont have enough reputation to add a comment), I'd reply to Dean Richardson on how to do what he wanted, without any additional JS code. Pure CSS.

You would replace his `.btn` with the following:

```
<a class="btn showdetails" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#viewdetails"></a>
```

And add a small CSS for when the content is displayed:

```
.in.collapse+a.btn.showdetails:before { 
    content:'Hide details «';
}
.collapse+a.btn.showdetails:before { 
    content:'Show details »'; 
}
```

[Here is his modified example](http://jsfiddle.net/8cYFj/)

Comment: While useful, this is not portable to allow i18n, one of the reasons why content should not belong to CSS. In any case, +1 for this.

Comment: It's if the css is a block on the same file, or if you're pre-processing the CSS (to render Compass/Sass, minify or similar tasks)

Answer (score 11):

I wanted an "expand/collapse" container with a plus and minus button to open and close it.  This uses the standard bootstrap event and has animation.  This is BS3.

[image]

#### HTML:

```
<button id="button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></span> Show
</button>

<div id="demo" class="collapse">
  <ol class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item">Warrior</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Adventurer</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Mage</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

#### JS:

```
$(function(){
  $('#demo').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('#button').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></span> Show');
  })
  $('#demo').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('#button').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-up"></span> Hide');
  })
})
```

#### Example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/aG5BtH?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

html:

```
<h4 data-toggle-selector="#me">toggle</h4>
<div id="me">content here</div>
```

js:

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle-selector]').on('click',function () {
        $($(this).data('toggle-selector')).toggle(300);
    })
})
```