# Using button to expand a section below in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use the code provided in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968072/twitter-bootstrap-button-click-to-toggle-expand-collapse-text-section-above-butt/18219574#18219574) -

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span4 collapse-group">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <p class="collapse">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
    <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
</div>
```

and in general it works great. However, whenever I try to add anything like section headers within the paragraph tags, anything below it is not hidden. Is there a way to make everything within a certain area hidden, no matter what the styling? Must one use the paragraph tags or would there be another option? Thank you!

Comment: Can you make a fiddle out of it and share with us ?

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/68RXP/ ?

Comment: Hi all, here is what I mean. When I add in a title, it and the text following it do not hide before the button click. I'm sure it's something simple I'm doing wrong, but not sure. http://jsfiddle.net/aprinsen/j3NjB/4/

Answer (score 0):

This could be because the heading tags don't have the class "collapse". I'm new to HTML myself but when I was looking at your code that was something that I spotted. For example:

```
<h2 class="collapse">This is a title</h2>
```

Hope this helps!